# PHP to Java using Socket

Tags: java, php, sockets

I'm trying to send messages between Java and PHP using sockets, but I can't get it to work. I firstly tried Java to Java and that's working fine, but now I want to get PHP to Java and otherwise. The PHP said that the message was sent but Java don't get one. Could anyone help me with this?

Java server:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        final int portNumber = 81;
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
        while (true) {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os, true);

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Client response: " + line);
                pw.println(line);
            }
            pw.close();
            br.close();
            os.close();
            socket.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Java client:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client extends Thread {

    Socket socket;
    BufferedReader br;
    PrintWriter out;

    String disconnectReason;
    boolean disconnected = false;
    public boolean running;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client client = new Client();
        client.sendMessage("Hello!");
    }

    public Client() {
        new Thread(this).start();
        running = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            socket = new Socket("localhost", 81);
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            while (running) {
                String line;
                if((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("Server response: " + line);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Disconnected. Reason: " + disconnectReason);
            disconnected = true;
            running = false;
            br.close();
            out.close();
            socket.close();
            System.out.println("Shutted down!");
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if(e.getMessage().equals("Connection reset")) {
                disconnectReason = "Connection lost with server";
                disconnected = true;
                System.out.println("Disconnected from server. Reason: Connection reset");
            } else {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        if(running) {
            if (!disconnected) {
                if (out != null && socket != null) {
                    out.println(message);
                    out.flush();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PHP Code that i tried:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost"; 
$port = 81;
$data = 'test';

if ( ($socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === FALSE )
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " .             socket_strerror(socket_last_error());
else 
{
    echo "Attempting to connect to '$host' on port '$port'...<br>";
    if ( ($result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port)) === FALSE )
        echo "socket_connect() failed. Reason: ($result) " .     socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket));
    else {
        echo "Sending data...<br>";
        socket_write($socket, $data, strlen($data));
        echo "OK<br>";

        echo "Reading response:<br>";
        while ($out = socket_read($socket, 2048)) {
            echo $out;
        }
    }
    socket_close($socket);      
}
?>
```

EDIT:
Seems that commenting socket_read fixes the problem with receiving the message in Java, but still the problem remains how I can send from Java to PHP

Comment: i've commented the `socket_read` line in php and it was successful, the `test` received and printed in java console.

Comment: @MaMadLord ah, but how can I read the messages that I send from Java to PHP?

Comment: ok i found the receiving problem, you need to determine where is the end of your line with `"\r\n"` like initialize `$data` with `"test\r\n"` but still i don't know what is the reading problem.

Comment: Oh well that fixed it, thanks. PHP is receiving my data from Java also now.

Comment: yeah the problem was that i'd change your code a bit :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok found the problem, you have to show where is the end of the line in `php` so the socket could send it, and it will work like a charm :)

```
 socket_write ($my_socket, $data."\r\n", strlen ($data."\r\n"));
```